# How to perform crosstab according to condition in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `pandas` package to perform some data aggregation and manipulation. I have a code that looks like this:

```
df = df[df['OT'] == 'OT']
pd.crosstab(df['Delivery'], [df['Week'], df['Description']]).stack().fillna(0)
```

It generates the following output, which is correct:

```
Week                                       201909  201910  201911  201912  201913  201915  201917
Delivery                   Description
Normal                        CD               23     0.0     0.0     0.0      23     0.0       2
                              CDG              26     6.0     0.0     0.0      33     0.0       6
                              CDH              40     4.0     3.0     5.0      78     0.0       4
Fast                          CD                4     0.0     0.0     0.0       6     0.0       0
                              CDG               6     2.0     2.0     1.0       6     1.0       0
                              CDH               5     0.0     0.0     4.0       5     0.0       0
```

The problem is that there are also rows that have `Week` column with values `201914` or `201916`, though none of these rows that an `OT` column value that satisfy the condition I have for filtering (i.e. `df['OT'] == 'OT'`). Hence, initially they all get wiped out, and later there doesn't exist any row with column values for `Week` that equal `201914` or `201916`. But, what I want to do in my crosstab is that in such a case, I want to include all 0 values for that column. So, in my above example, the end result should also include a column for `201914` and `201916`, and all the values should be `0.0`. How can I achieve this with `pandas`?

Comment: Look at setting paramater `dropna=False` in `pd.crosstab`.

Comment: You can use `df_out = pd.crosstab(....)` then `df_out.reindex(df['week'].unique(), axis=1)`.

Comment: Try `df['Week']=df['Week'].astype('category')` before filter

Comment: @Wen-Ben Thanks, this seems to work, but then I get later in the code `ValueError: Categorical not ordered` error.

Comment: @Wen-Ben Is it possible to later change the type back to what it was before setting to `category`? Because later I perform some more manipulations.

Comment: `df['Week_for_cal']=df['Week'].astype('category')` and do manipulation on this column

Comment: @Wen-Ben I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Can you please write an answer with your proposed solution. Setting `df['Week']=df['Week'].astype('category')` before the filtering works, but then later I get error in the line `result.loc[:,f'{start}':]` that category is not ordered.

Comment: @Wen-Ben I see your answer got deleted. `df['Week']=df['Week'].astype('category')` helps to achieve the pivot table that I want, but then I perform all kind of other manipulations to it, and then it gives an error about categorical. I did not understand how or when I create a temporary column.

Comment: @terett just simple follow scott 's  solution df_out.reindex(df['week'].unique(), axis=1)

Comment: @Wen-Ben Scott's solution doesn't work, as I have the filtering `df[df['OT'] == 'OT']` before crosstab. Yours helped the get correct pivot data, but then you did not explain how to remove the categorical thingy.

Comment: @terett I did not explain much due to there is no sample data .. simple fix after pivot just do ,`df.columns=df.columns.astype(str)`

Comment: @Wen-Ben Thanks, this `astype(str)` worked. If you write it as answer with your previous thing, I can accept.

Comment: I will try to add it when I back to home

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190725/discussion-between-terett-and-wen-ben).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can check your column type to `category` , then when you done with manipulation of your data , just change the columns type back to str

```
df['Week']=df['Week'].astype('category')
s=pd.crosstab(df['Delivery'], [df['Week'], df['Description']])
s.columns=s.columns.astype(str)
s.stack().fillna(0)
```

Comment: @terett I have un-delete it :-)